# How do I get a list of process that have run on my linux box during the last hour or so?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to log processes that run over a period of time so that I end up with a tidy list of processes that have run over the the last hour or so?

top is great of realtime monitoring but i'm looking for a log of what new processes show up over a time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install and enable [process accounting](http://wiki.tldp.org/Process-Accounting). On a Debian-based Linux:

```
apt-get install acct
```

Then you can use `lastcomm`.

Comment: Haven't we met before? : )

Comment: Beware, you'll be using a chunk of disk space to do this.

Comment: Sure have. Thanks - that is the answer i'm looking for alright.

Answer (score 0):

`sar` might do this as well. Install it, configure it and run it as daemon.